# Linq - Consulta en lista de tercer nivel

Tags: c#, linq

tengo una lista de una clase (A) que contiene una lista de otra clase (B) y que a su vez contiene otra lista de otra clase (C).
Necesito filtrar la lista inicial (A) a partir del valor de una propiedad de la clase (C).
El ejemplo sería algo así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PruebaLinq
{
  public class Leage
  {
     public string NameLeage { get; set; }
     public List<Team> teams { get; set; }
  }

  public class Team
  {
     public string NameTeam { get; set; }
     public List<Player> players { get; set; }
  }

  public class Player
  {
     public string NamePlayer { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
  }


  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        #region Inicializar lista
        List<Leage> lista = new List<Leage>
        {
           new Leage
           {
              NameLeage = "Leage_1",
              teams = new List<Team>
              {
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_1_1",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_1_1_1",
                          Age = 20
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_1_1_2",
                          Age = 22
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_1_2",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_1_2_1",
                          Age = 19
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_1_2_2",
                          Age = 21
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           new Leage
           {
              NameLeage = "Leage_2",
              teams = new List<Team>
              {
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_2_1",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_2_1_1",
                          Age = 19
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_2_1_2",
                          Age = 22
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_2_2",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_2_2_1",
                          Age = 19
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_2_2_2",
                          Age = 21
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           new Leage
           {
              NameLeage = "Leage_3",
              teams = new List<Team>
              {
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_3_1",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_3_1_1",
                          Age = 20
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_3_1_2",
                          Age = 22
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 new Team
                 {
                    NameTeam = "Team_3_2",
                    players = new List<Player>
                    {
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_3_2_1",
                          Age = 19
                       },
                       new Player
                       {
                          NamePlayer = "Player_3_2_2",
                          Age = 20
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        };
        #endregion

        //Necesito obtener las ligas en que haya algún jugador de 20 años.
        //lista = ????????;

        Console.ReadLine();
     }
  }
}
```

Como indico en el comentario, lista debería contener sólamente las ligas Leage_1 y Leage_3

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Tienes una excelente respuesta de @AsierVillanueva, aunque en mi opinión deberías al menos haber mostrado si habias intentado algo y que problemas te habias encontrado. Pedir una solución sin demostrar haberlo intentado va en contra de la filosofía de SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que buscar las ligas que tienen algún equipo con algún jugador de 20 años:

```
    var filterList = lista.Where(l => l.teams.Any(t => t.players.Any(p => p.Age == 20)));
    foreach (var league in filterList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Liga con jugador de 20 años: {league.NameLeage}");
    }
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Como sugerencia, yo delvolvería una lista solo con el nombre de las ligas que es lo que pide el OP: _lista debería contener sólamente las ligas Leage_1 y Leage_3_.Algo así `var filterList = lista.Where(l => l.teams.Any(x => t.players.Any(p => p.Age == 20))).Select(x=>x.NameLeage).ToList();`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.